# Error passing a list to a function via multiprocessing queue module

Tags: python

I'm getting an weird error using queues/multiprocessing.  I basically have a function that takes a list then parses it.

I have to do this many times so I thought it would be a good idea to spread it over the cores I have and I tried to setup a queue but its not working.  Here's my code:

```
# Establish communication queues
tasks = multiprocessing.Queue()

# Start consumers
num_consumers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2
print 'Creating %d consumers' % num_consumers
worker = [ rules(tasks)
          for i in xrange(num_consumers) ]
for w in consumers:
    w.start()


def loadGraph(dayCurrent, day2Previous):



for dayCurrentCount  in graph[dayCurrent]:
    dayCurrentValue = graph[dayCurrent][dayCurrentCount]
    for day1Count  in graph[day2Previous]:
        day1Value = graph[day2Previous][day1Count]
        rulesDataToPass = [day1Count, day1Value, dayCurrentCount, dayCurrentValue, dayCurrent, day2Previous]

        tasks.put(rulesDataToPass)



tasks.close()
tasks.join_thread()
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Without using a queue it works fine.  The problem is my function requires multiple variables to run(before I was sending it individually but decided to bunch it all together as a list so I can queue it up).

please help!

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: as requested, here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lostsoul/Dropbox/code/learning/python/game.py", line 213, in <module>
    for i in xrange(num_consumers) ]
  File "Users/lostsoul/Dropbox/code/learning/python/game.py", line 191, in rules
    day1Count = dict[0]
TypeError: 'Queue' object does not support indexing
```

basically I have sending the data to a function I have called 'rules', the dict is then parsed like  day1Count = dict[0],..day1value dict[1]...etc.. I am basically trying to compare two dictionaries against each other. so the queue is from a nested for loop that pairs every entry together(adding it to the queue which I'm hoping will get processed on all my cpu's..it works right now individually but takes 15 min using one cpu).

UPDATE2:  Here is the rules function. Its simple. basically takes the values, and then passes them to other functions(its my version of a rules engine)

```
def rules(dict):
    day1Count = dict[0]
    day1Value = dict[1]
    dayCurrentCount = dict[2] 
    dayCurrentValue = dict[3] 
    dayCurrent = dict[4] 
    day2Previous = dict[5]
    exactSame(day1Count, day1Value, dayCurrentCount, dayCurrentValue, dayCurrent, day2Previous)
    withinFivePercentChange(day1Count, day1Value, dayCurrentCount, dayCurrentValue, dayCurrent, day2Previous)
    deleteNonEdgeNodes(dayCurrentCount, dayCurrentValue, dayCurrent)
```

Without queue this works fine.

Comment: Can you include the exception message and traceback that you get when running the script?

Comment: @chown Hey..thanks for the comment.  I updated the question with the message.  Hope that helps.

Comment: We need to see the body of `rules`.  It looks like you're attempting to index into whatever is being passed into it, which isn't working.

Comment: @g.d.d.c I updated the question with the rules function.  Basically its the poor man's version of a rules engine :-)  Let me know if you need any more info.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `TypeError: 'Queue' object does not support indexing` is indicating that your `dict` variable is of type `Queue` (which you probably dont want it to be).  Double check lines 191 and up to make sure you are properly assigning the `dict` variable properly.

---

Also, ***NEVER*** use a type name as a variable name.  `dict` is a type, you shouldn't use it as the name for a dictionary variable.  Use `my_dict` or something similar.  Its possible that by using dict as a variable name, your setting some other variable to a dict object, instead of assigning it the value of the dict variable.

See [`stdtypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) for more info on the `dict` class.

---

Heres the problem, your sending `tasks` which is a `Queue` to `rules()`, which is expecting an iterable type (list):

```
tasks = multiprocessing.Queue()
worker = [rules(tasks) for i in xrange(num_consumers)]

def rules(dict):
    day1Count = dict[0]
    day1Value = dict[1]
    dayCurrentCount = dict[2] 
    dayCurrentValue = dict[3]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm sorry I don't really understand what to do. Your logic makes sense and I think the command: tasks = multiprocessing.Queue() and tasks.put(rulesDataToPass) are making it like this but I'm not sure how to fix it.  

My reasoning was, my function takes a list(I wrongly labeled it dict..I changed that) but I want to queue all the lists so my cpu workers can process it so I must add my list to a queue which is passed to the function(which is expecting a list).  How can I pass a list via a queue to that function?

Comment: sorry, if I wrote that in a confusing way..I'm confused about sending data to functions via a queue.  I have done the examples and I can send a single variable, but not sure how to send a list.  Note, before I used a list I was sending 6 variables to the function but the queue rejected it.

Comment: the code is fairly large(400+ lines) and it generates alot of data which will take a long time to run on a normal machine.  I have a server I running the code on because it takes days on my laptop and desktop.  Plus I'm a newbie and I think no one would be able to follow my twisted logic(not even I can at times.lol).  Basically the above code works without queue, but I think your right just not sure how to send a list to a queue to process.

Comment: I just did and got the same error..TypeError: 'Queue' object does not support indexing

Comment: Check my edit again.  Your sending tasks to the rules() function.  But you cant call [0] on a `Queue`.

Comment: I understand that now, but not sure how to get the list to the function using queue.  For this function to work, it needs 6 variables but it doesn't matter if its individually or in a list.  The problem is the queue rejects it if its individually and gives me this error if I put it in a list.  I'm not sure how others are using queues to pass more than one variable to function..

Comment: I did that before and rulesDataToPass works fine while in the for loop(that is how it was before) but its not multiprocessing..I thought I could take that list and pass it to a queue to allow multiple cpu's to work on it..

Comment: I was under the impression that I could start workers on each of the cores I had that monitored the queue(which I thought I did above) then as data enters the queue they start to process it(in this case run the rule function on each core for the different datasets in the queue).

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  You have to create multiple Treads, then start those threads running the `rule` function in a `while True:` loop, add objects to the `Queue` then in the `rules()` function you would get an object from the queue and process it.  Then it would process in multiple threads at the same time.  I'll toss up an example when I get back to my PC, but look at the example at the bottom of this page: http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html

Comment: Thanks..I have a feeling I am putting data into the queue correctly but maybe not retrieving it correctly.  I saw task.get() and tried that but it just stops the application..I think it is possible to send a list using queue, otherwise queue's and multiprocessing would be so limited.

Comment: You can, and the way you did it now with `tasks.put(rulesDataToPass)` is correct, the error was because `rules(tasks)` is incorrect; you need to pass it a list, or move that code below the loop and pass it `rulesDataToPass`.